# Excel 2010 VBA - pasting rows to end of table gives "Type Mismatch" Error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm copying data from one table where there are calculations and appending it to a static table for archiving. The tables have the same number of columns.

Wehn I run the macro below, I get a "Type mismatch" error.

```
Sub CopyTable(t As String, destSheet As String)
    Dim srcRng, destRng As Range

    Set srcRng = Range(t)
    srcRng.Copy
    Set destRng = Sheets(destSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1)

    destRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Set srcRng = None
    Set destRng = None

End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me why and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace **None** with **Nothing**.

Comment: Thanks - was coding in Python all day before I opened Excel, was blind to the mistake.